# How to change font in innerHTML new window?

Tags: html, css, fonts, receipt

I have to change font in the new window of window.open() because I want to print in receipt printer. I already change the True Type Font Subtitution but it doesn't work . So how can I add css for the new open window ??
here's my code :

```
<img src="barcode.png" id="barcode">


<script type="text/javascript">
function printImg() {

    ImageLink=document.getElementById("barcode").src;
    pwin=window.open('','','width=0,height=0');
    pwin.document.write("<center><h>My Store<h><br>Ekiosk</center><br>Date : <?php echo date('Y/m/d'); ?><br>Time : <?php echo date('H:i:s'); ?><br>Customer Name: <?php echo $cust['firstname']; ?> <?php echo $cust['lastname']; ?> <br>Total : <?php echo $cust['total']; ?><br><center><img src='" + ImageLink + "'/><br>Thanks For Shopping !</center>");
    pwin.print();
    pwin.close();    

}
</script>
```

Can anyone help me to change font into font receipt ?

Comment: You could always add it in the document.write as an html wrapper with style="font-family:xxx;" added. Not sure if this is the correct way, but it should work. Is there any external CSS applied to this window already?

Comment: I already tried that way . but it doesn't work . there's no external CSS applied . because I don't know how to put the class in the document.write .

Comment: I meant simply with: `pwin.document.write("<div style="font-family:somethinghere;"> .... your content </div>");` Or do as Jonathan suggests, especially if you need to add more CSS to the window (which I would assume you do.)

Comment: if we put quotation mark inside pwin.document.write("....") , like pwin.document.write(" .. " ".. " ) , the function didn't work . So I cannot put <link href="your.css" ... /> inside this.

Comment: Use single quotes. 'your.css' or use singles to wrap the code: .write(' ... ');

Answer (score 0):

Add a CSS file

```
<link href="your.css" ... />
```

Just like you're doing with your `pwin.document.write` sentence

You should also write a full valid html code in the document.write, including html, title, head and body tags, and put the link inside the head tag, like you use to do in any other page.